# Can't detach and delete morphToMany relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my model, I have a morphToMany relationship

public function expenses()
{
return $this->morphToMany(Expense::class, 'expensable');
}

I'm trying to remove the relation from the `expensables` pivot table and remove the item from the `expenses` table.

```
public function deleting(Wallet $wallet)
{
    // FIRST TEST 
    $wallet->expenses()->detach(); // Detach the "wallet" from table "expensables" => GOOD but don't remove the "expense" from table "expenses"
    
    // SECOND TEST
    $wallet->expenses()->delete(); // Delete the "expense" from table "expenses" but don't remove the "wallet" from table "expensables"

   // THIRD TEST
   $wallet->expenses()->detach(); 
   $wallet->expenses()->delete();
   // Doesn't work, I can't do that, It detaches properly but then I can't remove the expense element.
}
```

How can I do ?

I would really like to detach `Wallet` from the `expensables` table and remove the expense from the `expenses` table

Thank you

Comment: have you tried doing the delete first? since after you do the detach there won't be anything left to delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damn…

The comment from @lagbox is the only possibility that I had not tested and it worked.

I did :

```
public function deleting(Wallet $wallet)
{
    $wallet->expenses()->delete();
    $wallet->expenses()->detach();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: well glad you got it working ... its  lagbox  btw  ;)